# Listview Adapter and Listener in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, actionbarsherlock, adapter

I am having trouble with my listview adapter and Listener. I am kind of new to Android and I think I set it up correctly. I want my onclicklistner to just display the name of the selected list item. Eventually I want it to do more. Whenever I try to run this tab I get a force close. It leads me to believe there is an issue before the onclicklistner. am I constructing a SherlockList Fragment incorrectly?

```
public class HerbsFragment extends SherlockListFragment  implements ActionBar.TabListener{
private View herbView;
/** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
String organs[] = new String[]{
        "Liver",
        "Kidneys",
        "Eyes",
        "Heart",
        "Blood"
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    herbView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView)(herbView.findViewById(R.id.listview));

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, organs);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), 
                 "You selected :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

    return herbView;//inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {     
    super.onStart();

    /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

}
```

I posted the logcat

```
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.HerbsFragment.onCreateView(HerbsFragment.java:43)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
06-29 23:49:56.911: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My listview is defined in my main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: can you post the logcat details of the crash?

Comment: I added the logcat details

Comment: listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: looks like listView is null. check if listview is null

Comment: I updated my question to show my listview. Yes it is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this and your class extends `SherLockListFragment`.

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

So initialize ListView as

```
 ListView listView = getListView();
```

Comment: I did that but now I get an error saying:   

06-30 00:10:14.729: E/AndroidRuntime(15224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: ListView listView = getListView() and keep this android:id="@+id/list" in xml fir listview.

Answer (score 1):

Change the id of listview in xml file like android:id="@android:id/list", change in java file also like, ListView listView = (ListView)(herbView.findViewById(android.R.id.list));